# Taking median of calculation in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, median

MyTable in SQL Server contains _TimeStamp, Column1, Column2, and Column3, which have the following values:

```
_TimeStamp Column1 Column2 Column3  
'2010-10-11 15:55:25.40' 10  3  0.5  
'2010-10-11 15:55:25.50' 20  9  0.7  
'2010-10-11 15:55:25.60' 15  2  1.3  
'2010-10-11 15:55:25.70' 17  8  2.7  
'2010-10-11 15:55:25.80' 42  6  3.6  
'2010-10-11 15:55:25.90' 14  2  0.4
```

I would like to find the [median](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median) value of 4*Column1*Column2*Column3.  The products for each row are:
           60
          504
          156
       1468.8
       3628.8
         44.8
Since there are an even number of entries, the median value is the average of the two 'middle' entries (156 and 504), or 330.  Also I only want to perform the median on values that fall within a chosen time range, and the solution can't alter the database which isn't mine.  I edited a [similar query](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2006/12/18/medians-row-numbers-and-performance.aspx) to get the query shown below, but it fails because a column name is invalid.  Any suggestions?

```
SELECT
  AVG(4*Column1*Column2*Column3)
  FROM 
(
  SELECT
    4*Column1*Column2*Column3,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
    ORDER BY 4*Column1*Column2*Column3 ASC, _TimeStamp ASC) AS RowAsc,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
    ORDER BY 4*Column1*Column2*Column3 DESC, _TimeStamp DESC) AS RowDesc
  FROM MyTable WHERE 
   _TimeStamp BETWEEN '2010-10-11 15:55:25.40' AND '2010-10-11 15:55:25.90' 

) x
WHERE 
  RowAsc IN (RowDesc, RowDesc - 1, RowDesc + 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all you need to do to your candidate statement is to alias the computed value in the subquery, then ask for the `AVG` of *that alias* in the outer query:

```
SELECT
  AVG(MyValue)
  FROM 
(
  SELECT
    4*Column1*Column2*Column3 AS MyValue,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
    ORDER BY 4*Column1*Column2*Column3 ASC, _TimeStamp ASC) AS RowAsc,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
    ORDER BY 4*Column1*Column2*Column3 DESC, _TimeStamp DESC) AS RowDesc
  FROM MyTable WHERE 
   _TimeStamp BETWEEN '2010-10-11 15:55:25.40' AND '2010-10-11 15:55:25.90' 

) x
WHERE 
  RowAsc IN (RowDesc, RowDesc - 1, RowDesc + 1)
```

I haven't tested this though.